# nginx with mod_wsgi

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, mod-wsgi, wsgi, flup

I generally run web apps behind [nginx](http://nginx.net) with FastCGI.  I wanted to experiment with mod_wsgi, however it seems quite out of date.  The author mentions that it worked on version 0.5.34, however I'm running 0.7.62 now.

The [wiki article](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxNgxWSGIModule) warns of compilation problems with the module and later versions of nginx.  Has anybody used mod_wsgi with more recent versions of nginx?  Is there another module out there that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For nginx other options are FASTCGI, Phusion Passenger or proxying. You could also just use the original mod_wsgi with Apache instead, fronting it with nginx for static file handling if necessary.

For nginx/mod_wsgi ensure you read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/05/blocking-requests-and-nginx-version-of.html

Comment: Definitely won't be using Apache, but thanks.  FastCGI has been working pretty well so far behind nginx.

Comment: +1/accepted because I think the general answer to mod_wsgi with nginx is "don't do it".  :-)  I have been using FastCGI for a while now and will continue to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm setting this up too, and I'm just curious - why not reverse-proxy nginx to a multi-threaded paste wsgi process?

Comment: This is basically what I've been doing, though not with paste.  I was more curious as to the state of mod_wsgi with nginx, but I now understand there are more technical limitations given nginx's async/event-driven model.